# Для чего нужен Reflection API в PHP? Практическое использование

Tags: php, рефлексия

Читая книгу Котерова "PHP 7 в подлиннике" познакомился с Reflection API.
Как работают отражения, написано предельно доступно и понятно. Но, нет ни одного живого примера где это может использоваться на практике. Пока что, единственная практическая польза которую я для себя отметил - это генерация документации. Но ведь не только же для этого создавался этот механизм?
Мне как джуниору с достаточно небольшим опытом работы очень интересно, в каких случаях отражения используются при решении рабочих задач? Хотелось бы настоящих, живых примеров.

Comment: Чтобы понять всю мощь и удобство reflection, вам для начала придется разобраться с тем, что такое метапрограммирование и для чего оно нужно, а так же с паттернами проектирования, потому что некоторые из них могут реализованы с помощью reflection. Но я бы на вашем месте сильно не увлекался её, потому что насколько мне известно, в php она работает крайне медленно.

Comment: @Axenow в 7м пхп рефлексия довольно быстра, емнип. Тем не менее, в отсутствии таких вещей как атрибуты (как в том же rtti делфей или шарпа) весьма ограничивает его использование в прикладных задачах.

Comment: Ну камон, ребят, расскажите о прикладных задачах то. В этом ведь вся суть вопроса!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вышла хорошая статья, описывающая ответ на мой вопрос с примерами. Оставлю тут, может кому то пригодится https://habr.com/post/433266/